# Leaflet Map - second Polygon makes the first layer unclickable

Tags: r, popup, leaflet, layer, polyline

I am working on a map of American Community Survey data. Currently I have a primary layer (seen below as `plotMerge$incomePerCapita`). It works well, has a fully fleshed out popup, image and all. When I add a second layer, to provide county and regional boundaries, the tract boundaries become un-clickable, seemingly masked by the new layer.

If I swap the layer order, the regional boundaries become invisible.

```
map1<-leaflet()%>%
  addTiles()%>%

addPolygons(data = plotMerge,
          fillColor = ~pal(plotMerge$incomePerCapita),
          color = "#000000", #this is an outline color
          fillOpacity = 0.8,
          weight = 0.2,
          popup=popup)%>%
addPolygons(data = countyPoly,
            fillColor = "transparent",
           color = "#000000",
           stroke = TRUE,
           weight = 1,
           smoothFactor = 0.5,
           group = "Counties")%>%
addLegend(pal = pal,
            values  = plotMerge$incomePerCapita,
            position = "bottomright",
            title = "State-wide Income Percentiles",
            labFormat = labelFormat(digits=1))

saveas(map1, "map1.html")
map1
```

Is there a way to show just the outline of a boundary in a second layer, yet leave the full functionality of the previous layer intact?

Should I be scripting the addPolygons in a different way to show the boundary without imposing a functionally obscure layer?

UPDATE:

I fixed an error and swapped the `addPolygons` code to get the layers in the right order.

```
map1<-leaflet()%>%
  addTiles()%>%
addPolygons(data = countyPoly,
            fillColor = "transparent",
           color = "#000000",
           stroke = TRUE,
           weight = 1,
           smoothFactor = 0.5,
           group = "Counties")%>%
addPolygons(data = plotMerge,
          fillColor = ~pal(plotMerge$incomePerCapita),
          color = "#000000", #this is an outline color
          fillOpacity = 0.8,
          weight = 0.2,
          popup=popup)%>%
addLegend(pal = pal,
            values  = plotMerge$incomePerCapita,
            position = "bottomright",
            title = "State-wide Income Percentiles",
            labFormat = labelFormat(digits=1))
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: without data hard to test, but maybe you could use Show/Hide Layers to have access to both layers (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are working with proper spatial objects using `sp`, you can coerce your `countyPoly` into a `SpatialLines(DataFrame)`:

```
countyLines <- as(countyPoly, "SpatialLinesDataFrame")
```

Then you should be able to click the underlying polygon layer while showing the lines on top.

EDIT:
As a reproducible example you can try:

```
library(mapview)
library(sp)

pol <- as(gadmCHE, "SpatialPolygons")
ln <- as(gadmCHE, "SpatialLines")

mapview(gadmCHE, color = "blue") + pol # not clickable
mapview(gadmCHE, color = "blue") + ln # clickable
```

Comment: I am working with really proper spatial objects created on an arcGIS server prior to being shared with us. This is fabulous. I find it difficult to know how the package objects play with each other. This is very helpful!

Comment: As a tip, make sure you understand spatial classes first, then mapping with **leaflet** (or **mapview**) is a walk in the park.

Answer (score 0):

With `leaflet_1.1.0`, it seem that the solution proposed by @TimSalabim does not work anymore.
You can now use  `addPolylines` instead of `addPolygons` to solve the problem.

Comment: can you elaborate on what exactly doesn't work anymore?

Comment: I have a chloropleth map and I add administrative boundaries on top of it. Both are `sp` `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and  are added with `addPolygons` to the leaflet map as in the original question. The popups and labels of the choropleth map are no more available when I do that. If I transform the administrative boundaries into `SpatialLines` and add it to the leaflet map with `addPolygons` the popups and labels are not available. If I add directly the administrative boundaries (polygons) with `addPolylines` it works, I can see the labels and popups.

Comment: How does that mean that the solution above doesn't work anymore? It uses `mapview` not `leaflet`directly. And internally `mapview` will use `addPolyLines` when you pass a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` to either the mapview call itself or via `+`. Please let me know if the line `mapview(gadmCHE, color = "blue") + ln` from the solution above does not enable polygon querying.