# Making a Leaflet layer clickable or unclickable without reordering

Tags: r, leaflet

Unsuccessfully finding the answer in SO or Google, then successfully finding a solution on my own, I decided to both pose the problem and answer at once.

Reproducible code can be found below in the "Answer".

### Problem

All layers are "clickable" by default. Therefore, when using more than one layer, particularly when on overlays another (e.g. markers and polygons), the order in which you layer determines what is clickable. Markers overlayed with Polygons will remain unclickable, even if no labels are popups accompany the Polygons.

The only post I found talking about this issue was: [Leaflet Map - second Polygon makes the first layer unclickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217985/leaflet-map-second-polygon-makes-the-first-layer-unclickable)

The naive solution is to ensure the markers are layered last. Unfortunately, if you use functions like `addLayersControl()`, enabling/disabling a layer moves that layer to the front. Therefore, while the layer order matters *initially*, it doesn't truly "solve" the problem.

Answer (score 9):

### Solution

Use the functions `pathOptions()`, `markerOptions()`, and `labelOptions()` accordingly.

In my case, it was the polygon layers that were causing the issue. These are made "unclickable" by doing `addPolygons(..., options = pathOptions(clickable = FALSE))`.

### Example

```
library(rgdal) # for spatial data
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

# download and load state border data
url <- "http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2015/shp/cb_2015_us_state_5m.zip"
temp <- tempfile(fileext = '.zip')
download.file(url, temp)
unzip(temp, exdir = dirname(temp))
states <- rgdal::readOGR(file.path(dirname(temp), "cb_2015_us_state_5m.shp"),
  layer = "cb_2015_us_state_5m", verbose = FALSE)
unlink(temp)

# code adopted from https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shapes.html
neStates <- subset(states, states$STUSPS %in% c(
  "CT","ME","MA","NH","RI","VT","NY","NJ","PA"
))

cities <- read.csv(textConnection("
City,Lat,Long,Pop
Boston,42.3601,-71.0589,645966
Hartford,41.7627,-72.6743,125017
New York City,40.7127,-74.0059,8406000
Philadelphia,39.9500,-75.1667,1553000
Pittsburgh,40.4397,-79.9764,305841
Providence,41.8236,-71.4222,177994
"))


# (1) polygon layer added last; cannot click cities/circles
map_1 <- leaflet(neStates) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addCircles(data = cities, lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, weight = 1,
    radius = ~sqrt(Pop) * 30, popup = ~City,
    group = "Cities") %>%
  addPolygons(
    stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.2, smoothFactor = 0.5,
    color = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", states$AWATER)(AWATER),
    group = "States") %>%
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c('Cities', 'States'),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))


# (2) polygon layer made 'unclickable' (clickable = FALSE)
map_2 <- leaflet(neStates) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addCircles(data = cities, lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, weight = 1,
    radius = ~sqrt(Pop) * 30, popup = ~City,
    group = "Cities") %>%
  addPolygons(
    stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.2, smoothFactor = 0.5,
    color = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", states$AWATER)(AWATER),
    group = "States",
    options = pathOptions(clickable = FALSE)) %>% # DISABLE 'clickable'
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c('Cities', 'States'),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))


map_1 # even if polygon layer is put last, disable/enable layer puts it in front again
map_2 # disable/enabling any layer has no impact!
```